# How to make plane which cover 360angle in Unity3d

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, textures, plane

I want to make a plan which cover 360angle, and my device camera remain inside of this 360 angle plan. I can also able to show some textures on it. When user move camera toward right then plan should move toward left and vice versa. Actually what I want to achieve I am making Geocaching app in Unity. I will have to show 2d and 3d objects with help of compass. So how can i achieve this in unity, if someone have any idea lets share with me. Thanks in advance?

Comment: I think you want to view the inside of a cylinder effectively?

Comment: I can set cylinder but there is no way to show texture inside cylinder we can set outside of cylinder. How to show texture around camera?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to flip the direction of the face normals of your cylinder to make the texture appearing from inside the cylinder. Have a look at this [Blender model](http://files.scio.de/public/SO/Cylinder.blend) to get an idea. In Blender (the only modelling software I know) you have to select all faces in edit mode and then click *Flip Direction* in tool shelf. Then you can proceed with UV mapping as usual.